# How to use these 2 rest services in AngularJS, also how to call requrest for jwt from spring backend

Tags: angularjs, spring, rest, jwt

I am trying to consume rest services but don't know how to call web services in angularjs from spring backend, also want to know how to integrage json web based token which I have written in spring backend in angularjs.

**Webservice 1 : Login for admin**

```
URL: <http://200.201.4.12:8080/liberary/authenticateUser>
Request type: POST
Header type: Content-Type application/json
Parameters: {
    "username":"darek",
    "password":"dark99"
}
```

**Webservice 1 : Login for user**

```
URL: <http://200.201.4.12:8080/liberary/authenticateUser>
Request type: POST
Header type: Content-Type application/json
Parameters: {
    "username":"polo",
    "password":"polo33"
}
```

**My Code is:**

```
authService.login = function(user, success, error) {
    $http.post('misc/users.json').success(function(data) {
        //this is my dummy technique, normally here the
        //user is returned with his data from the db
        var users = data.users;
        if(users[user.username]){
            var loginData = users[user.username];
            //insert your custom login function here
            if (user.username == loginData.username && user.password == loginData.username) {
                //set the browser session, to avoid relogin on refresh
                $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(loginData);

                //delete password not to be seen clientside
                delete loginData.password;

                //update current user into the Session service or $rootScope.currentUser
                //whatever you prefer
                Session.create(loginData);
                //or
                $rootScope.currentUser = loginData;

                //fire event of successful login
                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginSuccess);
                //run success function
                success(loginData);
            } else {
                //OR ELSE
                //unsuccessful login, fire login failed event for
                //the according functions to run
                $rootScope.$broadcast(AUTH_EVENTS.loginFailed);
                error();
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `$http.post` with a json file (Do not know where it comes from

You should replace it with the URL of your webservice + the data

```
$http.post('http://200.201.4.12:8080/liberary/authenticateUser',
     {"username" : "polo", "password" : dark99}).then(function(data){

    //Do what you want with the data returned from your webservice
}, function(error){
    //Handle error
});
```

NOTE : You only have **1** webservice which is located on 200.201.4.12:8080

Comment: Your answer is correct so will check the answer, however the data i was temporarily fetching in front end from json file. Weedoze can you guide my how to call and integrate token in the in angular code, which i have written in spring backend.

Comment: I don't really know how this works but you can easily find tutorial on google with "AngularJS authentification token" for example

Comment: Weedoze no prob, thanx for your help.

Comment: No problems, hope you fill find what you need